# What is the difference between requiring url module and creating instance of url class in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, url, module

I am learning NodeJS and got confused while working with urls.

I am not able to get the idea on how is requiring module of url (`const url = require("url")`) and creating new instance of URL class, for example `const myURL = new URL()` are different.

Can they both work independent of each other ?, or requiring url module is necessary to use URL class ?

Comment: Anything used in code must be available in the current scope. `require` makes code available (there are other ways). How that code is used depends on what's being required.

Comment: I created the URL class instance without requiring the url module, I still got the result right

Comment: Then `URL` is available in the current scope already.

Answer (score 1):

`const url = require("url")` gives you the original Node.js url module.

`URL` gives you the new URL class that is compatible with the standard URL class used in browsers.

There's a [comparison](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects) in the Node.js documentation.